# Polars - invalid column type integer when reading sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, python-polars

I tried to use Polars to read data from my SQLite database:

```
conn = 'sqlite://'+pathToDB
querystring = "SELECT * FROM table1"
msgt1SAT = pl.read_database(querystring, conn)
```

However I got an error:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid column type Integer at index: 1, name: unixtime
```

Yes - Polars are absolutely correct that I have an column named Unixtime that is of integer type. (**Actually this is wrong, it is saved as timestamp in the sqlite database. Is this whats making the query fail?**)

Edit:
I've recreated a sample of the database setting the datatype as integer instead of timestamp - now I get `Invalid column type TEXT at index:0` (different column)). If Polars/connectorx can't handle any of sqlite's datatypes, how is this even released?

Comment: Does it work if you bypass polars and just do the connection with connectorx?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thank you, I tried that as well - getting the same error. After 11 minutes it ended with the same error. Since it is taking so long, wonder if that means that there might be a row wit an unexpected datatype in it? It surely can't be that they can't handle integer. (Actually, it is saved as "TIMESTAMP" in the sqlite database, maybe that is why?)

Comment: "If Polars/connectorx can't handle any of sqlite's datatypes, how is this even released?" this is a good rhetorical question. The answer 99.9% of the time is that it wouldn't have been released or at least it wouldn't be a popular release. If you recognize that the software wouldn't be released and hugely popular if it couldn't handle simple data types then, and I'm not saying this to be a jerk, it means you're the one doing something wrong. It seems like you have a column of data that has mixed types between datetime, text, and or integers and that is why it's not working.

Comment: What does the data actually look like? Can you provide a runnable example? e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/tests/unit/io/test_database.py - Have you tried `engine="adbc"`?

Comment: Not taking it as you being a jerk @DeanMacGregor - after all I am asking for help on what I am doing wrong. I think you might be correct in that suggestion. I'll try to reproduce to see if it doesn't accept sqlite timestamp (as it gets int), file a bug report and in any case raise an issue regarding that error msg as it should say (what you explain) outright. Thx!